# Tracking another git-repository

Tags: git, version-control, redmine, gitosis

I try to set up a development environment "redmine", that should make it easy for multiple people to develop and maintain our own version of "redmine" including our own features and adjustments. I'm not that familiar with remote branches, but I thought of a config like this:

- *master* branch: for deployment
- *dev* branch: here we're developing our new features
- *community* branch: this is where i got stuck. I'd like have a branch which is tracking the github community repo of redmine, so that I can say in this branch 'git checkout v2.0' and then in the dev branch 'git merge community' and solving merge conflicts to due to our own features there. After the next redmine relase I would then checkout v2.1 in the community branch and merge it to the dev branch again and so on ...

Of course, I can add a remote to my local branch, pull from the community repo and push to my origin, but then the other people wouldn't see that and would have to add the community remote repo themself (right?). Is this possible or what is another approach to solve this 'track a reference project in my own project' problem?

Thanks

Jan

BTW: my *origin* repo is created using gitosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you are in your *dev* or *community* branch (working arena), you will need to use feature branches to develop, edit, and propose your developments so that the can be brought together in a structured manner. That is, you should choose an approach to merging contributions and to promoting them to a higher level. [git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows)

Do take the time to understand the way remotes work, and that the tracked branches are exact duplicates (up to the point of the common fetch/push), so you cannot plan to have different people's contributions allocated the the same *community* branch - that's why each person should have their own feature branch. You can re-use branch names once the feature is complete.

git itself ([github.com/git/git](https://github.com/git/git)) has a published sequence of branches:- *pu* (potential updates), *next*, and finally *master*. Before *pu* there are individual contributor branches (each built from patch series submissions in the git list's case), and *pu* can be rewound if/when the maintainer needs. *next* is more stable. Users fetch updates and rebase their work on the relevant latest release.